# WORD VBA - Radio button click populates textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help with a simple word radio button click.

The word document is a simple work instruction, the user has an option of three different radio buttons which i want to populate a specific instruction in a text box.

Currently using the code:

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
TextBox1.Value = "Work instructions for North West Region Standpipes"
End Sub
```

This code only seems to work properly if my .value is one line of text.

Is there a way to do this with entire paragraphs that are specifically formatted?

Should i be using a different method other than activex textbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `vbCrLf` is newline, as is `vbnewline` . there is also `vbtab` ....... `TextBox1.Value = "Work instructions for" & vbnewline & "North West Region Standpipes"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that your textbox's Multiline property is set to True you can display any paragraph formatted in Word. I tried this code where the bookmarked range included both hard and soft returns.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox1.Text = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Mark").Range.Text
End Sub
```